# Carregar um elemento em ajax conforme escolha do usuário

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho um código que insere um campo `textearea` conforme uma escolha de `input` radio. Gostaria de simplificar esse código fazendo com que use só JavaScript. É possível? Segue abaixo:

**HTML**

```
<p>2.3 - Você estuda? </p>
<input type="radio" name="estuda" id="estuda" value="1" required=""> Sim 
<input type="radio" name="estuda" id="estuda" value="2" required=""> Não 
<div id="ret-ajax"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#estuda').change(function () {
  var chars = (this.value);
  $.post(URL + 'Ajax/pesquisa', {val: chars}, function (busca) {
  $('#ret-ajax').html(busca);
 });
});
```

**Ajax**

```
$char = $_POST['val'];
$body = '';
if($char == 1){
     $body .= '<textarea name="curso" rows=4></textarea>';
  }
   elseif($char == 2){
     $body .= '';
}

$retorno = $body;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tinhas um erro grave no teu html, não pode haver dois id's iguais (`#estuda`), podes colocar como classe (`.estuda`), faz o seguinte:

```js
$('.estuda').change(function () {
  var chars = parseInt(this.value);
  if(chars === 1) {
    $('#ret-ajax').html('<textarea name="curso" rows=4></textarea>');
    return;
  }
  $('#ret-ajax textarea').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>2.3 - Você estuda? </p>
<input type="radio" name="estuda" class="estuda" value="1" required=""> Sim 
<input type="radio" name="estuda" class="estuda" value="2" required=""> Não 
<div id="ret-ajax"></div>
```

Comment: Valeu amigo, funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: De nada @EduardoSantos. Ainda bem que sim

Answer (score 1):

Você não deve usar um mesmo `id` para dois elementos diferentes.
http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_global_id.asp

Dito isso, sugiro você remover a função `$.post` e fazer a comparação no próprio JavaScript. Algo como:

```
$('#estuda').change(function () {
  var chars = (this.value);
  if(chars == 1)
     $('#ret-ajax').html('<textarea name="curso" rows=4></textarea>');
  else
     $('#ret-ajax textarea').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

O atributo `id` deve ser único, mas você pode obter as entradas pelo `name`, adicionar um ouvinte (listener) para cada radio button e criar um `textarea` caso seja a opção 1. Com Javascript puro pode ser algo mais ou menos..

```js
// obtém todas os elementos com name estuda
var entradas = document.getElementsByName("estuda");

// adiciona um listener change para cada um 
for (var i = 0; i < entradas.length; i++) {
  entradas[i].addEventListener("change", criar);
}

// funcao que verifica o valor do radio 
function criar() {
  if (this.value == 1)
    document.getElementById("ret-ajax").innerHTML = '<textarea name="curso" rows=4></textarea>'; // innerHTML adiciona um conteudo HTML ao elemento
  else
    document.getElementById("ret-ajax").innerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<p>2.3 - Você estuda?</p>
<input type="radio" name="estuda" id="estudaS" value="1" required="">Sim
<input type="radio" name="estuda" id="estudaN" value="2" required="">Não
<div id="ret-ajax"></div>
```

Comment: Valeu amigo. Isso mesmo.